# How to configure new NewRelic key on my servers and code to monitor application on new account created

Tags: node.js, performance-testing, newrelic

Earlier i have used new relic to monitor application servers. My new relic trial version has expired now. I have created new account on new relic. Where and what are the changes i need to make in my code to monitor my application on new account. My application is hosted on 5 servers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application is a Node.js application, I recommend following the instructions provided here:

- [Install the Node.js agent](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/install-nodejs-agent)

Assuming the "key" in your title means the license key, the location where this is defined is described here:

- [license_key](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/installation-configuration/nodejs-agent-configuration#license)